# Converting string to key and vice versa

Tags: java

I have problem with converting Key (security) to string and next convert it to that object. I have some errors:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 20`

and my code:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpairg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpairg.initialize(1024);
KeyPair kpair = kpairg.genKeyPair();
Key publicKey = kpair.getPublic();

// to String
String textFromKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded());

// to Key
byte[] byteKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(textFromKey.getBytes());
X509EncodedKeySpec X509publicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(byteKey);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
Key pubb = kf.generatePublic(X509publicKey);
```

`textFromKey is sending to UDP server` 
`textFromKey is a output from server if I want to use that key`
I saw some answers in that website but anything help me. Could you look at this?

IDE told me that there is a problem:
`byte[] byteKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(textFromKey.getBytes());`

Comment: The illegal character is 20 (hex) i.e. space. If you print for example `"AAA="` and `"AAA= "` they look the same visually but are different and the latter is illegal in 4648. Check the string you are decoding is _exactly_ the same. Or if you want to add space use `getMimeDecoder()`; MIME allows stray non-base64 characters.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is not clear from just the code. Can you try doing just

```
X509EncodedKeySpec X509publicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.getEncoded());
```

and get back?